# Python: os.chdir does not work in Python?

Tags: python, operating-system

I have the below code snippet and the function `chdir` doesn't seem to work..

```
cwd_path = os.getcwd()
print("CWD: " + cwd_path)
changed = os.chdir(r"C:/CISCO/PYTHON/My_Learning/prank")
print(changed)
```

The below is the output:

```
CWD C:\CISCO\PYTHON\My_Learning
None
```

Comment: As far as i'm aware os.chdir doesn't have an output, hence the none. So it' will have changed directory it just doesn't print anything. if you try another os.getcwd() after you've changed directory that should do it.

Comment: Why do you conclude that hasn't worked? It isn't documented to return anything, what were you expecting to get back?

Comment: [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) does not return anything.

Comment: @FullName: Of course `os.chdir` returns something. It returns `None`.

Comment: @Matthias 'not anything' == None ;)

Comment: I was just in the mood of being pedantic. ;-)

Comment: @Matthias Sometimes we all are :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm) os.chdir returns None in all the cases.

Comment: Posting a link is not an answer.

Comment: @FullName That's not *just* a link. It's the answer (`os.chdir` returns `None` in all cases) with a link as a reference. However it surely isn't a very good answer since 1) lacks proper formatting 2) Links to external sources instead of the official python documentation 3) Uses *here* as a link anchor. In any case *it is an answer*.

Answer (score 1):

`os.chdir` returns `None`.

In that case, you should set `changed` as a flag that checks if the current directory is the same as the last one:

```
cwd_path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r"C:/CISCO/PYTHON/My_Learning/prank")
changed = (cwd_path != os.getcwd())
print(changed)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir` doesn't return anything back to you. When you want to see what directory you are in you want `os.getcwd`. E.g.

```
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('/')
print(os.getcwd())
```

Outputs something like;

```
/my/home
/
```

Answer (score 0):

os.chdir does not have a output, you have to make a os.chdir() then make:

```
    changed = os.getcwd()
```

that way you get the new directory